# Port forwarding (P2P connection)

Tags: c#, portforwarding

Im experiencing a strange situation which i was supposed to handle.

The situation is: 2 routers (with static IPs by ISP) and 2 host computers behind each router. Let's say IP addresses are R1_IPAddr(router 1), R1_IPAddr_LocalH1(host 1 behind router 1) are 1st group and R2_IPAddr(router 2), R2_IPAddr_LocalH2(host 2 behind router 2) are belong to 2nd group.

So, my aim is: To connect R1_IPAddr_LocalH1 with R2_IPAddr_LocalH2.
Here what I did: My server code (C#) on R2_IPAddr_LocalH2 and R2_IPAddr router forwards port 5000 to R2_IPAddr_LocalH2 (configured but may require other settings). Server code binds R2_IPAddr_LocalH2 on 5000 port number and waits connection where R1_IPAddr_LocalH1 machine tries to connect to R2_IPAddr router on port 5000.

NOTE: router hasn't any firewall options, means the cheapest one :) and tested my code on local LAN, working fine!

If somebody has any ideas to share pls?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i have not made this capability yet, I found a good write up on the capabilities Microsoft made, partially explaining the NATUPnP 1.0 Type Library, which is used for configuring and managing port forwarding.

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer mr. you are rich with technology :)
Now, my question goes to you again :) I didn't configure my router to forward 5000 port to my host machine. However, when I register port forwarding on local machine (in NAT table with the program you posted) it is working fine. So, from this point router is not forwarding but machine is asking to forward 5000 port from router. Is is true or am I confusing?

Comment: You are correct, the program essentially tells the router to direct all data on port xxxx to your computer to handle data transfers. That's how bitTorrents work.

Comment: awesome! thanks to verify my point. wish you to be a richer :)